# Calling a specific contact endpoint with Lync

Tags: call, contacts, lync, endpoints

I'm trying to develop a Lync application that allows a user to select which of a contact's endpoints they would like to call. For instance, if User A has two phones listed, then User B can choose between those two options and call whichever he likes to try and get in contact with them. I know with the regular Lync Client(not suppressed) this appears to be possible, but Im not sure how to accomplish it programatically in UISuppression mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be mistaking your question for something different ... but is this not just the difference between calling a sip uri and calling one or more tel uris.

So... in the Lync client, people can "Call Lync" me, which will start a call to my sip uri, or they can see my Work and Mobile numbers, and place a call to either of those, which will then call a tel uri call.

If I sign into Lync on my mobile (creating two endpoints) then other people still only see one option to "Call Lync" me, and it's down to my own settings whether I get simultaneous ring or forward-ring, or whatever.

You can get a contacts tel URI details from their `contact` object, and place calls just as you would a sip uri call, however instead of placing a call to `sip:user@domain.com` you use `tel:+4412345654321` etc.